# How to use to find the placement of a object in a list

Tags: python, list, indexing

My current problem is I want to search for items in a list but only for the number of items in said list

```
drumsound = ["0"]
def AddSnare():
  drumsound.append("1")
  print(drumsound)
  
def AddTom():
  drumsound.append("2")
  print(drumsound)

def beat(): 
  a = 1
  for x in drumsound:
   if drumsound[a] == "1":
    mixer.music.load("soundfiles/snare.mp3")
    mixer.music.set_volume(1)
    mixer.music.play()
    a += 1
   
   elif drumsound[a] == "2":
     mixer.music.load("soundfiles/tom.mp3")
     mixer.music.set_volume(1)
     mixer.music.play()
     a += 1
```

My problem is if in this line `if drumsound[a] == "1":` i can use `[a]`as a variable or a way i can do something simmaler

Comment: For one, `drumsound[a]` is redundant here. `x` is already `drumsound[a]` so `x == "1"` would suffice.

Comment: If I understand your question, just test `x` in place of `drumsound[a]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this by having a `list` of function objects rather than having some magic number (`"1"`, `"2"`) associated with a sound.

In python, functions are first class objects so you can pass them around, assign them to variables, append them to `list`s, etc.. and they won't actually do anything until you use the parentheses `()` to call them.

That allows you to do something like this:

```
def play_snare(mixer):
    mixer.music.load("soundfiles/snare.mp3")
    mixer.music.set_volume(1)
    mixer.music.play()
  
def play_tom(mixer):
    mixer.music.load("soundfiles/tom.mp3")
    mixer.music.set_volume(1)
    mixer.music.play()

def beat(drumsounds, mixer):
    # here func will be play_snare, play_tom, and play_snare
    # because of the list defined below
    for func in drumsounds:
        func(mixer)

drumsounds = []
drumsounds.append(play_snare)
drumsounds.append(play_tom)
drumsounds.append(play_snare)
beat(drumsounds, mixer)
```

When you iterate over a `list`, python does you a favor and unpacks the `list` as you are iterating.

So:

```
a = 0
for x in drumsound:
    print(drumsound[a])
    a += 1
```

is doing the exact same thing that this would:

```
for x in drumsound:
    print(x)
```